# How to find text in webpage through PHP?

Tags: php, find, lookup

I have a pure text file without any HTML formatting. I want to search for a word in it? how should i do that? and I also want the next words before a comma. can i do that to?

so means:
if its: `"word1":"i like stackoverflow", next thing`

i want to find `word1` which is in inverted commas and then i want the whole phrase `i like stackoverflow` without the inverted commas. and it should stop at that point.

is there any way to do that?

thanks...

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php . Then it is just a matter to loop and find the things you're looking for

Comment: You are looking for regex. This should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). In PHP, you can use a function like [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to do this.

For the pattern you described, your regular expression code could be something like:

```
$match_array = array();
$string_to_match = // load the string from a file and put it in this variable

preg_match('/"([A-Za-z0-9\s]+?)":"([A-Za-z0-9\s]+?)"/', $string_to_match, $match_array);
```

The results of the match will then be placed in `$match_array`.

Comment: hey thanks for that... but i will not know the string "i like stackoverflow" i will just know the word1... so is there any way to ask it the next word or describe the formatting and then ask it?

Comment: Yes, that's what the code I posted above does. The second parameter is the string you are searching, so I used the string you posted above. I'll update the code so it's a little clearer.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer and modification hansengel, but the code did not work. the file is on some other server. then i query the file and take it to my server by file_get_contents() function. then i did whatever you told. i even tried changing the values and added substr too. but in the end it did not work. its giving me an empty array. what should i do? and can u explain me preg_match more in detail... thanks...

Comment: `preg_match` is a PHP function to search a string for a given regular expression. If you need more specific help with your code, please edit your original question and post your latest attempt. That way I can try to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: hey... thats ok, i did a but of tweaking to my code and changed the pattern. and it worked... thanks a lot for the answer... and i used preg_match_all... thanks a lot... :D